# BFS or DFS for a social network follow model

Tags: graph-theory, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I'm trying to implement a social network follower graph.

The requirement is like this, for simplicity, we can assume the profile of each user u  in the graph to be represented by a positive integer value P[u]. I am asked to provide a dating service. The goal is to generate a good dating partner for each user u. A partner is good if that person is reachable through a chain of follows whose profile is exactly the same as u (if any).

This is a graph traversal problem, I can implement it myself but the question here is that I'm not sure if using DFS or BFS is better in this case?

Answer (score 1):

From the complexities perspective, both algorithms run in O(V+E). While from the memory space perspective, DFS is better than BFS. So if you do care about memory, DFS would be better for you. Putting memory on aside, you are only to know which algorithms work best for you. For instance, you might prefer a good partner which closer to the user comparing to other partners. A user might have many good partners. So if you want to find a good partner which is closer first, BFS will do that for you. Otherwise, no difference. Looking to the example below, DFS(1) might return 8 or 7 as a good partner for 1. While running BFS(1) you will always get 7 first as a good partner for 1.
[image]